# What is the usage of other "*Block" and "With*"?

Tags: scoping, undocumented

There exist some "kernel functions" that are related to the built-in [scoping constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html):  `` Assumptions`AssumptionsBlock ``, `` Internal`HandlerBlock ``, `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``, `` Internal`LocalizedBlock ``, `` GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected ``, `` GeneralUtilities`SetupTeardown ``, `` Internal`WithTimestampsPreserved ``, `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``, `` Reduce`WithInternalSolveOptions ``, `` Internal`WithGroupTheoryOptions ``, `` Progress`EvaluateWithProgress ``, and `` System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules ``. As you can see, each of them
is relevant to one carefully defined construct for localization and modularization, which may provide some "environment" for certain purposes (at least in the literal sense of the Symbol). Regrettably, I cannot find a full description of these commands apart from `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``, `` Internal`LocalizedBlock ``, `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``, and `` Internal`WithTimestampsPreserved `` (but a detailed *official* documentation is still lacking). Are they really useful in writing actual programs? And how do I utilize such private subroutines (if possible)?
**Note.** This is not a thorough record; `` ?*`*Block* `` and `` ??*`*With* `` return *too many* undocumented (and confusing) symbols involving scoping.

Comment: Please refine that list to exclude symbols that are discussed on e.g. this page: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=InheritedBlock

Comment: If they are undocumented then you don't need to care though they can be useful but without guarantee they won't change in future.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for your suggestions. The reason is: I remembered that I saw some "internal" codes which do use these modules (particularly ```Internal`WithLocalSettings```) when I traced some statement with ```TraceInternal->True``` (or printed certain procedures via ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions```), but unfortunately, I have forgotten these specific names. It would be great if someone is willing to make a summary of those blocks.

Comment: Note that `Internal\`WithLocalSettings` became `WithCleanup`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, may you give some typical examples of using `WithCleanup` to implement the functionality of ``Internal`WithLocalSettings``? (Unfortunately, I cannot find such examples on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WithCleanup.html.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Any use of `Internal\`WithLocalSettings` can be replaced by `WithCleanup`. If you want to know what the former does, you can check documentation for the latter since it is a `System` context function.